# How I print number of list one forward, back end use python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, printing

I am a try to do for loop print a list of the number one of the forward and other from the back end.
Example: input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], output: [1,8,2,7,3,6,5]

Comment: Have you tried writing any Python code yourself yet?

Comment: Stackoverflow may help you to solve a programming task. But it is not a free service to do tasks instead of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo operator `%`:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

out = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    out.append(lst[len(lst) - i // 2 - 1 if i % 2 else i // 2])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question.
You can iterate in half of its range and print list[i] and list[len(list)-i-1].
-1 because backward indexing starts from 1.

Comment: Consider adding more details and code examples with proper formatting in your answer. It helps to understand it better. Refer [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

```
box = []

while mylist:
    x = mylist.pop(0)  
    box.append(x)

    while mylist:
        m = mylist.pop(-1)
        box.append(m)
        break

return box
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, I appreciate your comment.